# What is the correct way to implement concurrency in wcf service?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0, service, concurrency

I am trying understand concurrency in wcf and downloaded a sample code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and#) and done some changes for testing two way calls. To my surprise I could not see the effect of concurrency for two way calls (Although I can see concurrency for one way calls). 
Is it the way WCF concurrency model works? (or)
Am I doing something terribly wrong?

This is the service code.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHelloWorldService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void Call(string ClientName);

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
}
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    bool boolValue = true;
    string stringValue = "Hello ";

    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get { return stringValue; }
        set { stringValue = value; }
    }
}
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    public static int counter;

    public HelloWorldService()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public void Call(string ClientName)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Instance:" + counter.ToString() + " Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance:" + counter.ToString() + " Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance:" + counter.ToString() + " Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + " Time:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return composite;
    }
}
```

This is the service hosting code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create a URI to serve as the base address

        //Uri httpUrl = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8001/HelloWorld");
        Uri httpUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8010/MyService/HelloWorld");

        //Create ServiceHost
        ServiceHost host
        = new ServiceHost(typeof(ClassLibrary1.HelloWorldService), httpUrl);

        //Add a service endpoint
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ClassLibrary1.IHelloWorldService)
        , new WSHttpBinding(), "");

        //Enable metadata exchange
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

        ServiceThrottlingBehavior stb = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
        stb.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
        stb.MaxConcurrentInstances = 100;
        stb.MaxConcurrentSessions = 100;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(stb);


        //Start the Service
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service is host at " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

This is the client code.

```
class Program
{
    static int m_NumberOfWorkers = 10;
    static readonly object m_Locker = new object();
    static bool flag_GO = false;
    static Stopwatch m_OverAllStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    static ConcurrentBag<Stopwatch> m_bagIndividualStopwatch = new ConcurrentBag<Stopwatch>();
    static int m_CompletedWorkers = 0;
    static ServiceReference1.HelloWorldServiceClient m_objProxy;
    static int m_KindOfMethod;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                flag_GO = false;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter number of concurrent clients:");
                m_NumberOfWorkers = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Kind of method (1: One way, 2: Two way 3: Two way using data contract):");
                m_KindOfMethod = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                // Create Workers
                List<Thread> lstThreads = new List<Thread>();
                for (int i = 0; i < m_NumberOfWorkers; ++i)
                {
                    lstThreads.Add(new Thread(WaitOnPulse));
                }

                // Start Workers
                for (int i = 0; i < lstThreads.Count; ++i)
                {
                    lstThreads[i].Start();
                }

                m_objProxy = new ServiceReference1.HelloWorldServiceClient();

                m_OverAllStopwatch.Restart();

                // Signal all workers
                lock (m_Locker)
                {
                    flag_GO = true;
                    Monitor.PulseAll(m_Locker);
                }

                // Wait all workers to finish
                for (int i = 0; i < lstThreads.Count; ++i)
                {
                    lstThreads[i].Join();
                }

                m_objProxy.Close();
                m_objProxy = null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
        }            
    }

    private static void WaitOnPulse()
    {
        lock (m_Locker)
        {
            while (!flag_GO) Monitor.Wait(m_Locker);
        }
        TestWhatEverYouWant();
        IamDone();
    }

    private static void TestWhatEverYouWant()
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        switch (m_KindOfMethod)
        {
            case 1:
                m_objProxy.Call(m_NumberOfWorkers.ToString() + "Client Calls");
                break;
            case 2:
                m_objProxy.GetData(m_NumberOfWorkers);
                break;
            case 3:
                ServiceReference1.CompositeType objData = new ServiceReference1.CompositeType();
                m_objProxy.GetDataUsingDataContract(objData);
                break;
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        m_bagIndividualStopwatch.Add(stopWatch);
    }

    private static void IamDone()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_CompletedWorkers);
        // Summarize results if all workers are done
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_CompletedWorkers, 0, m_NumberOfWorkers) == m_NumberOfWorkers)
        {
            m_OverAllStopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("OverAll Elapsed Time: {0}", m_OverAllStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Stopwatch stopWatch;
            while (m_bagIndividualStopwatch.TryTake(out stopWatch))
            //foreach (Stopwatch stopWatch in m_bagIndividualStopwatch)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Individual Elapsed Time: {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Cleint trace:

```
    Enter number of concurrent clients:
    8
    Kind of method (1: One way, 2: Two way 3: Two way using data contract):
    2
    OverAll Elapsed Time: 42022
    Individual Elapsed Time: 42021
    Individual Elapsed Time: 37013
    Individual Elapsed Time: 32008
    Individual Elapsed Time: 26987
    Individual Elapsed Time: 21981
    Individual Elapsed Time: 16980
    Individual Elapsed Time: 11968
    Individual Elapsed Time: 6985
```

This is the server trace:

```
    Instance:1 Thread:6 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:29 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:5 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:34 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:7 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:39 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:7 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:44 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:5 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:49 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:7 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:54 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:5 Time:12/17/2012 8:09:59 PM


    Instance:1 Thread:7 Time:12/17/2012 8:10:04 PM
```

For these results you can clearly see that the requests were processed sequentially. Ideally I was expecting all the 8 concurrent requrest would finish in 5 sec. But it took around 42 sec to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code is the way the proxy is used. I have created just one proxy for all concurrent clients and all calls to the service were made through this proxy only. So, all these calls were getting queued in the channel. ***Creating one proxy for each client***, the way one should simulate wcf load test, solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I still think the problem is with settings; proxy and number of threads originating from each proxy, the link explains it well.

Also have a look at following link; may be test client can have a problem.
[Seeking WCF Duplex "TwoWay" Subscribe+Callback Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472679/seeking-wcf-duplex-twoway-subscribecallback-example)

Comment: link-only answers are not helpful. If you do provide a link it should be in support of your answer. Link-only answers also lose their meaning entirely if/when the link goes dead.