# Two way communication between asp.net application and windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to have this type of communication using `signalR`: The two applications are not on the same machine I want the ASP.NET application sends some data to Windows application, Windows application makes some processing then sends data back to ASP.NET application.

Any ideas, how to acheive this?

Comment: If I were you, I'd set up a WCF Service - most likely in the website. The App connects to the endpoint and subscribes to events. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472679/seeking-wcf-duplex-twoway-subscribecallback-example

Comment: What is the exact requirement? If its just to access some functionality, you could abstract the code used in windows application to a class library and consume in both windows and web app. WCF with web and tcp endpoints would be ideal.

Comment: No, it's not just functionality it' s an e-voting system i have many applications and i want them to talk to each other is it possible , is there anyway simpler than WCF it seems a little bit complicated to configure

Comment: I found many ways to have a connection but which one would be the best Sockets, WCF, SignalR

Comment: SignalR uses Web Sockets, Server Sent Events, Long Polling and Forever Frame based on what is supported on the client and the server. It abstracts away the decision to use a particular method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use SignalR but you will need to set-up a server (using SignalR) that controls the flow of information between the applications. For more details, refer to the documentation here: 
http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: Thanks all for replies, i've read about signalR but the given examples alwayes gives the client application as an html page in the asp.net application how can we make the client a desktop application

Comment: Hi abnanda, Do u mean i have to host signalR in a separate application ana send and receive messages between applications by this server?????

Comment: Yes. We have .NET4/45 and WinRT clients as well. The documentation explains how to use the .NET clients.